# Rspec Rails: testing controller method 'create' with a multi-model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, update-attributes

I am building a Ruby on Rails app with the usual assortment of models, views and controllers.

The 'create' action in one of my controllers is supposed to create an instance of two different models.  Here's my code:

```
 def create
  @league = League.new(params[:league])
  @user = @league.users.build(params[:user])
  ... .save conditions appended ...
 end
```

So, when you call 'create' through the LeaguesController via a POST request to /leagues, you get a new instance of League and a new instance of User.  I also want the new User instance to inherit the ID of the new League instance, so it can be used as the foreign key to link the instances together.  This is accomplished with:

```
 def create
  @league = League.new(params[:league])
  @user = @league.users.build(params[:user])
  @league_id = @league.id
  @user.update_attribute('league_id', @league_id)
  ... .save conditions appended ...
 end
```

The User model already `belongs_to` the League model, which `has_many` users.

The above code works just fine and dandy, verified via manual testing.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to automate these tests with Rspec.  I'm trying to be a good boy and use test-driven design, but this has me stumped.

The issue is that I can't figure out how to access the attributes of the newly created instances of League and User in my tests.  I am attempting to do so using the following code:

```
describe LeaguesController do
  describe 'new league and user' do
    it 'should create a new user with a league_id equal to the new leagues id'
      @league_attr = { :name => "myleague", :confirmation_code => "mycode", :id => 5}
      @user_attr = { :username => "myname", :password => "mypass"}
      post :create, :user => @user_attr, :league => @league_attr
      assigns(:league_id).should eql(5)
    end
  end
end
```

But the test returns `nil` for the value of `:league_id`

I'm new to both programming in general and Rspec in particular, so I really appreciate any help someone might offer!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `:id` with `new`. Try this:

```
 def create
   @league = League.new(params[:league])
   @league.id = params[:league][:id] if params[:league][:id]
   @user = @league.users.build(params[:user])
   @league_id = @league.id
   @user.update_attribute('league_id', @league_id)
   ... .save conditions appended ...
 end
```

That said, I wonder how come it works in the browser.

Also, you better off using [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or Fixtures to assign data to models when testing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Wawa Loo.  I think it's working because I don't actually have to assign `:id`.  It is automatically assigned every time a new model instance is created.  I am just reading the value that's already there and assigning its value to a different attribute in a different model instance.

Comment: Actually, a new does not assign `id`. It has to be saved first. I think it't working because your doing `@user = @league.users.build(params[:user])`, the `@league_id = @league.id` line does not do anything helpful. 
(Please consider accepting the answer if it's what you were expecting)

Comment: Well, your tests are doing their job. They told you that there was a problem with your controller action create: its not good to provide an `:id` as params, and when saving 2 associated models, you should use another method (a transaction - for sure - that creates the user, the league and pass until they are associated correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [pry](http://pry.github.com/)?

Whenever I discover something like this I find it very handy to be able to insert a brakepoint via Pry (or Ruby-Debug) so I can inspect the variables and their behavior.

I suspect putting in a `binding.pry` between `@league_id = @league.id` and `@user.update_attribute('league_id', @league_id)` may very well shed some light on the issue.

Also note that user will automatically inherit the @league_id when you persist it via the `@league.save` call. (that's the idea behind `@league.users.build(..)` - it will set the required relationships correctly upon persistance.

Comment: Thanks Tigraine, I will check out Pry.  I feel confident in the way the method is working (it behaves as expected), but I want to automate the testing using Rspec so that I can make sure I don't break this functionality as my app gets more complex.